# Storing small and simple persistent data on Google App Engine Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, backend

I need to know what's the best way to store persistent data on google app engine in a situation like mine:

I only need to store a few relatively small amounts of data (a few hashmaps of strings to strings, with no string exceeding over ~300 characters). i'm estimating maybe maximum usage is 5 of these hashmaps and 3000 keys per hash map... The data needs to be around indefinitely, and will be updated once every ~30 minutes. would REALLY prefer not to have pay for service, as it would require a ton of beaurocratic procedures (corporate policy).

I've been trying to wrap my head around how data storage really works on app engine...

1. can i just continue to use a `static HashMap<String, String>` to store all the data? this is how i currently have my deployment set up, and it seems to be working just fine for the past couple of hours (no data reset). i dont think i have any `backend instances` or anything set up.
2. how long can i expect this data to last if it is in memcache or jcache? the documentation says it's volatile, but if something is used incredibly infrequently, will it just stay forever in cache?
3. I've been looking at the Datastore options, but i'm so confused on what/if anything will cost money.
4. can i store it in just like a raw .txt file somehow??

any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a little table on the DB, so that you have your pairs stored on a non-volatile place. You cannot rely on Memcache if these data should be preserved.
for point #4, you cannot use the filesystem on backend instances.

Hope this helps

Comment: do you know if this will end up costing money for small storage?

Comment: listening to this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas up to 5GB is free

Comment: Correct Cristiano.  Your main two options for persistent storage are datastore or cloud storage. For this small amount of data, datastore is probably the best bet.